# Adding get attachment page url

Tags: php, wordpress

```
            <?php 
            $logos = get_field( 'client_logo_ids' ); 
            echo do_shortcode('[gallery ids="' . $logos . '" itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="p" columns="8"]'); 
            ?>
```

Trying to get attachment page url to work on this. Any suggestions?

Comment: It is unclear what you're trying to achieve. Please elaborate.

Comment: I'm waiting the above code to have a href of the images attachment page so when the img is clicked it will direct user to attachemtn url

Comment: Share the code of your shortcode function.

Comment: I should just be able to add link="file", but wordpress hates my face

Comment: Glad you sorted it out!

Answer (score 0):

Put  var_dump on $logos

```
var_dump($logos);
```

and give us the result.

I think, the url should be:

```
cho do_shortcode('[gallery ids="' . $logos['id'] . '" itemtag="div" icontag="span" captiontag="p" columns="8"]');
```

Comment: TY sir, I will try this out. I should have to only do link=, but this theme for client is so gutted half of things don't work